# Serialization of a Callback

Tags: java, serialization, javafx, callback

My application has some settings that can be configured, and some generate warnings. I need a way to preserve those warnings even if the application has been closed.

My warnings are structured as it follows :

```
public class CustomWarning implements Serializable {
    private final WarningType warningType; // enum
    private final String title, description;
    private final CustomCallback resolution;

    public CustomWarning(String title, String description, CustomCallback resolution, WarningType warningType) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.resolution = resolution;
        this.warningType = warningType;
    }

    public WarningType getWarningType(){
        return warningType;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public CustomCallback getResolution() {
        return resolution;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof CustomWarning){
            return ((CustomWarning) obj).getWarningType() == warningType;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The context is the following : An user, for example, wants to set the logging output to HIGH. This will decrease the performance of the app, and thus a warning is generated. This warning will contain a title ("High output") and a description ("You have set HIGH as Logging") and will be displayed in a `Dialog`. Here is the function that shows my warning in the `Dialog` :

```
// This will show a new dialog with title, description, and resolve/close buttons
Optional<Boolean> result = DialogFactory.getInstance().createShowWarning().showAndWait();

if(result.isPresent() && result.get())
    myWarning.getResolution().run(); // calls the "callback"
```

By pressing the "Resolve" button on the `Dialog`, it will get my `CustomCallback` and invoke the `run()` function, which can be, for example, show the configuration panel for the logging options.

The CustomCallback is just an interface :

```
public interface CustomCallback extends Runnable, Serializable {}
```

What would be the best way to preserve a `List<CustomWarning> warnings` after closing the app ? The following have been checked, but none seemed to work correctly :

- Serialization of the `List<CustomWarning>` : Was a bit difficult, since the serialization from the Java API also serializes the parents, and I don't want to serialize every controller I have in my app.
- Serialization of the class name / method name of the callback : Couldn't find a way to call the callback without the instance of the class, which I can't always recreate or provide.

Are there any other possibilities for the ways I've mentionned, or any new ideas ? Every comment is welcome.

Also : No external library would be better

Comment: is this app an Android app? If so, please add a tag. If it is Android, there are mechanisms to preserve app state.

Comment: No, this is a JavaFX app, sorry I forgot to mention it. Also using JDK 1.8